# What would be the function to make a formula false?

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> Produce counterexample to show that the following wfs is not logically
>   valid:
>
> $$(\exists x)(\forall y)(A (x,y)\land ¬A (y,x)\implies[A (x,x) \iff A(y,y)])$$

I've tried this interpretations  to see that wfs is not valid but none work:

Domain=$\mathbb N, A(x,y)=x<y$

Domain=$\mathbb N, A(x,y)=x=y$

Domain=$\mathbb N, A(x,y)=x>y$

Domain=$\mathbb N, A(x,y)=x$ and y are even/odd

Comment: take variables over the empty set, then $\exists x$ fails.

Comment: @JairTaylor The empty set? what's that? the empty has nothing but empty.

Comment: Can you see what $(\exists x)(\forall y)[A(x,x) \Longleftrightarrow A(y,y)]$ implies about relation $A$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi The reflexive relation?

Comment: Almost.  $A$ is reflexive if $A(x,x)$ is true.  What if $A(x,x)$ is false?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi then $A(x,x)$ is not reflexive :)

Comment: Not quite.  It says that $A$ is either reflexive (every element is related to itself) or irreflexive (no element is related to itself).  It rules out everything in between.

Comment: Now look at your four attempts for $A$.  How would you classify them with regard to reflexivity?

Comment: @JairTaylor I agree that the empty set is a countermodel to this formula, but the traditional convention in first-order logic is that all structures are nonempty.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I don't know

Comment: Is the relation on the natural numbers $x<y$ reflexive, irreflexive, or neither?  That is to say, is $x < x$ ever true?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi reflexive ? I don't know it's very confusing

Comment: Recall that a relation $\bowtie$ is reflexive if $x \bowtie x$ is always true and is irreflexive if $x \bowtie x$ is always false.  A strict order ($x < y$) is a typical example of irreflexive relation.  Clearly the same holds for $x > y$.  What about $x=y$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I see, $x=y$ is reflexive

Comment: Correct!  The last one (even/odd) depends on precisely what you meant.  Suppose it meant $A(x,y)$ is true if and only if both $x$ and $y$ are even or both of them are odd.  Then is it possible for $A(x,x)$ to be false?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi no, $A(x,x)$ is always true.

Comment: Correct again!  Now, we have established that all your examples of $A$ are either reflexive or irreflexive.  So they all satisfy the consequent of the implication ($A(x,x) \Longleftrightarrow A(y,y)$).  However, to make an implication $X \Longrightarrow Y$ false, you need $X$ to be true and $Y$ to be false.  So, you see why your examples didn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71895/discussion-between-michelle-and-fabio-somenzi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two HINTS

First, you have the statement:

$$(\exists x)(\forall y)(A (x,y)\land ¬A (y,x)\rightarrow [A (x,x) \leftrightarrow A(y,y)])$$

(I replaced the $\implies$ with $\rightarrow$ and $\iff$ with $\leftrightarrow$, since the former ones are typically used for meta-logical claims about logical implication and equivalence)

but you want it to be false. OK, so we want:

$$\neg (\exists x)(\forall y)(A (x,y)\land ¬A (y,x)\rightarrow [A (x,x) \leftrightarrow A(y,y)])$$

to be true.  Well, it may help to push the negation inside:

$$\neg (\exists x)(\forall y)(A (x,y)\land ¬A (y,x)\rightarrow [A (x,x) \leftrightarrow A(y,y)]) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$(\forall x)(\exists y)(A (x,y)\land ¬A (y,x)\land \neg [A (x,x) \leftrightarrow A(y,y)]) \tag{*}$$

This is probably a little easier to work with and think about then the original. For example, from this it should be clear that the relation $A$ cannot be symmetric.

Second, if the 'typical' worlds don't work as counterexamples, you could just try to come up with a world that has one or more objects $a$, $b$, $c$, ..., that do or do not stand in some relation $A$ to each other, without even trying to interpret what those objects and what that relation even means.

In fact, to do this somewhat systematically, you could first just consider a world where there is one object $a$, see if we can construct a counterexample, and if not, add more objects as needed. Now, with one object you're not going to be able to satisfy $(*)$, since you would need both $A(a,a)$ and $\neg A(a,a)$.

OK, but what if we add a second object $b$? Well, that's not going to work either: disregarding the biconditional, you need $A(a,b)$, and $\neg A(b,a)$ to satuisfy the statement for $a$, but you also need $A(b,a)$ and $\neg A(a,b)$ to satisfy the statement for $b$, so you get a contradiction there as well.

OK, then what about adding a third? Or maybe a fourth?  Try it and see what happens. Of course, as you get more objects, you may want to start using a little table to keep track of what relations you do or do not have, i.e. something like:

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
A&a&b&c&d\\
\hline
a&1&1&0&0\\
\hline
b&0&0&..&..\\
\hline
c&1&..&..&..\\
\hline
d&1&..&..&..\\
\hline
\end{array}

Good luck!